# How can I refer to the branch when both a branch and a tag point to the same commit?

Tags: bash, git

I have written an alias to output the N last checked out branches

```
git config --global alias.last '!f() { for i in $(seq 1 $1); do git name-rev --name-only @{-$i}; done; }; f'
```

...and it works *almost* fine.

```
$ git last 4

some-branch
some-other-branch
tags/some-tag^0
yet-another-branch
```

Problem is, of course, line 3 of output, when a ref (in this case `@{-3}`) points to a commit referenced by both a tag and a branch. It outputs the tag by default while I'd prefer the branch name (when there's one).

I tried a few things, namely using `^{}` to dereference the tag, but to no avail.

Do you, by any chance, see what I'm missing, and know how to dereference the tag here?

---

**Update after accepted answer : working version of the alias**

```
git config --global alias.last '!f() { for i in $(seq 1 $1); do git name-rev --name-only --exclude=refs/tags/\* @{-$i}; done; }; f'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow only branches:

```
git name-rev --name-only --refs=refs/heads/\*
```

or exclude tags:

```
git name-rev --name-only --exclude=refs/tags/\*
```

Comment: I opted for the second solution, thanks a lot. Final version for those interested : `git config --global alias.last '!f() { for i in $(seq 1 $1); do git name-rev --name-only --exclude=refs/tags/\* @{-$i}; done; }; f'`, used with or without a numbered parameter : `git last` gives only the last, while `git last 3` gives, well, you got the idea.